# How does fetch select the Origin header of an HTTP request in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, cors, fetch-api

I'm adding context for my question but the purpose of my question is general knowledge about how [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) sets the `Origin` header.

Context:
I'm trying to fake a CORS error. I have tests on a node project, and those tests send a fetch to a local http server by running: `fetch('http://localhost:4544/test/404', {method: 'GET'})`. The fetch returns a 404 on the tests.

However, when I run the exact same fetch from the browser's console, while being on stack overflow, I get the expected 404 plus:

```
    Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:50337/test/404' from origin 'https://stackoverflow.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:9000' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

And when I look at the network request in the developer tools, `Origin`'s value is stackoverflow.com.

However, if I run the same fetch on an empty tab's console, I get a different thing:

```
GET http://localhost:50337/unit-test/404 net::ERR_FAILED
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

since the `Origin` header is not set from what I can see when I inspect the network request in the developer tools.

For some reason, the debugger for my code does not allow me to go into `fetch()` (this is in Visual Studio Code, using JestRunner extension), so I have no idea what `Origin`, if any, is being sent on the request of a node app test that does not have a frontend

How does fetch decide the origin? How does it decide on a node application? How does it affect CORS requests?

Comment: It's most likely not at all about whether and how the Origin header is being set but rather the fact that, outside a browser environment, the client doesn't enforce CORS (because it doesn't have an origin so there's nothing to be "cross").

Comment: It might not be `fetch` itself which sets this header.  The browser may be setting it.  As for how it affects CORS, that's an entire subject in and of itself (and one which has a variety of duplicates on Stack Overflow).  Taking a step back... What actual problem are you trying to solve?  Why does it matter specifically where in the underlying system this header value is set, if at all?

Comment: Our application calls a bunch of analytics URLs at different points, and I'm trying to log the HTTP errors, timeouts, connection errors, etc.. But some of the URLs might be enforcing CORS and we don't want to log the URLs that return a CORS error, those need to be ignored. 

But I can't find a good way to test how my 'logger' code behaves with CORS because it does not seem to be affected by CORS, while my colleagues insist that in production this happens (I'm relatively new here, so I trust they know about this).

Comment: _"some of the URLs might be enforcing CORS"_ - that's not how it works. The _client_ enforces CORS, in a browser environment; the server's job is to _support_ cross-origin requests (if appropriate - in many cases the browser client _shouldn't_ be directly hitting the API) by setting the relevant response headers on the preflight request. Recommended reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS.

Comment: Ok, so then fetch is unrelated to the Origin header, it's the browser that sets the origin header on the request before? after? while? executing the fetch(). And then the browser itself checks if the origin and the allowed origins match, and if they don't it partially fails the request? I still get 200 or 404 even when the request is blocked by cors on the browser.  

And servers could potentially implement CORS checks themselves, but it would be pointless since the origin is only set on browsers and you can fake an origin header with curl requests or from other servers. is this correct?